# yo angular not being issued correctly

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bower, yeoman-generator-angular

when I issue `yo angular` it prints out the following log but no files

```
yo angular

     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\    
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

Out of the box I include Bootstrap and some AngularJS recommended modules.

? Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? Yes
? Would you like to include Bootstrap? Yes
? Would you like to use the Sass version of Bootstrap? No
? Which modules would you like to include? angular-animate.js, angular-cookies.js, angular-resource.js, angular-route.js, angular-sanitize.js, angular-touch.js
identical app/styles/main.scss
 conflict app/index.html
? Overwrite app/index.html? overwrite
    force app/index.html
identical bower.json
identical .bowerrc
 conflict package.json
? Overwrite package.json? overwrite
    force package.json
identical Gruntfile.js
identical README.md
   invoke   angular:common:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
identical     .editorconfig
identical     .gitattributes
identical     .jshintrc
identical     .yo-rc.json
identical     .gitignore
identical     test/.jshintrc
identical     app/.buildignore
identical     app/.htaccess
identical     app/404.html
identical     app/favicon.ico
identical     app/robots.txt
identical     app/views/main.html
identical     app/images/yeoman.png
   invoke   angular:main:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
 conflict     app/scripts/app.js
? Overwrite app/scripts/app.js? overwrite
    force     app/scripts/app.js
   invoke   angular:controller:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
identical     app/scripts/controllers/main.js
identical     test/spec/controllers/main.js
y
y   invoke   karma:app


I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


   invoke       angular:route

   invoke           angular:controller:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
identical             app/scripts/controllers/about.js
identical             test/spec/controllers/about.js
   invoke           angular:view:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
identical             app/views/about.html
 conflict     test/karma.conf.js
? Overwrite test/karma.conf.js? overwrite
    force     test/karma.conf.js
identical     .travis.yml
y
y
npm WARN prefer global bower@1.3.1 should be installed with -g
Loading "connect.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'source-map'
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'
Loading "watch.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'qs'
Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'async'
Loading "ng-annotate.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'simple-fmt'
Loading "svgmin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'js-yaml'

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2015-04-03 07:14:06 UTC)
loading tasks   14ms  ▇▇▇▇ 3%
wiredep:app    330ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 81%
wiredep:test    27ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 7%
wiredep:sass    33ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 8%
Total 406ms

npm WARN unmet dependency /home/g/Projects/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn requires bower@'~1.3.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/g/Projects/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/bower,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.4.1
/
> phantomjs@1.9.16 install /home/g/Projects/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Looks like an `npm install -g`; unable to check for already installed version.
Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /home/g/Projects/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1428045256553/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64 -> /home/g/Projects/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /home/g/Projects/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/g/Projects/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/google-cdn requires bower@'~1.3.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/g/Projects/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/bower,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.4.1
karma-jasmine@0.3.5 node_modules/karma-jasmine

grunt-karma@0.10.1 node_modules/grunt-karma
└── lodash@2.4.1

karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher
└── phantomjs@1.9.16 (which@1.0.9, progress@1.1.8, kew@0.4.0, adm-zip@0.4.4, request-progress@0.3.1, npmconf@2.1.1, request@2.42.0, fs-extra@0.16.5)
```

I have already installed bower@1.3.1 for google-cdn part in the npm warn, no idea why it isn't working !

Comment: Have you tried  installing bower globally ? (with the -g option) : npm install -g bower

Comment: @ClémentBerthou yes, i installed bower using `npm install -g bower@1.3.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was weird. It was generating my files in another folder where i runned it for the first time. 
Yo generator worked after i restarted my os.